# How to change dropdown icon while show in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change `Bootstrap` dropdown Menu during `jQuery` toggleSlide will work.

While Menu is open then a Symbol will come and while menu is close then previous normal icon will show.

Menu Button to Click

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="othersID" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span>Others</span>
</a>
```

Dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="navbarDropdownMegaMenu2">
   <li class="dropdown-item">A</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#othersID").click(function(){
  $("#navbarDropdownMegaMenu2").slideToggle("slow");
  // I want to change here...........
  $("#othersID .dropdown-toggle::after").content('\f102')
});
```

Comment: You should have a container to place the icon in it. targeting text only is a tedious task and not a good practice

Comment: "targeting text only is a tedious task and not a good practice"-- what does it means?